# Unable to find `systrace.py` on my local android sdk folder

Tags: android, performance, android-sdk-tools, android-sdk-manager, systrace

How can I get `systrace.py` on my local android sdk folder as I'm unable to find the file at `/tools` and `/platform-tools`?

Below is the image for current SDKs installed on my local machine.

[image: ANDROID_SDK]

Following is the image for the current contents available for reference.

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like Google has stopped shipping systrace as part of platform tools recently:

```
This package used to contain systrace, but that has been obsoleted in favor of Studio Profiler, gpuinspector.dev, or Perfetto.
```

https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools#downloads

Comment: `systrace` is Removed. Use Studio Profiler/gpuinspector.dev/Perfetto instead.